# .gitignore でディレクトリを指定する際、末尾の / (スラッシュ) の有無は意味がある？

Tags: git

Next.jsのプロジェクトを作成したときの.gitignoreの一部を抜粋します。

`# next.js`の方はディレクトリの末尾に`/`がついていますが、`# production`の方は末尾に`/`がついていません。
この違いは何なのでしょうか？また、この末尾の`/`の有無は.gitignoreに限らず、一般的な表記なのでしょうか？

**例:**

```
# next.js
/.next/
/out/

# production
/build
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ディレクトリを指定する場合に末尾の `/` は特別な意味を持ちます。
(.gitignore に限らず、rsync コマンド等でも同様の扱いな場合が多いです)

**参考:**
[.gitignore の書き方。ファイル/ディレクトリの除外](https://www-creators.com/archives/1662)

> ##### 特定のディレクトリを追跡対象から除外する
>
> ディレクトリ配下のファイルを全て追跡対象から除外するときは、末尾に「/（スラッシュ）」を配置します。
>
> 末尾の「/」は特別な意味を持つ、「ディレクトリとその配下の除外」を意味する記号となり、仮に同じ名前のファイルが存在してもマッチング対象にはなりません。
>
> もしスラッシュがなければ、通常のパターンマッチングとなり、パスにマッチがみつかればそれを除外します。

Comment: ご回答いただきありがとうございました。